# Integral convergent or divergent?

Tags: convergence

How can I find out for what values of `r` (both lower and upper limits), is this integral convergent/divergent?

```
I = Integrate[(1/r^2)*BesselJ[0, (m/R0)*r]*D[BesselJ[0, (m/R0)*r], {r, 2}], {r, ?, R0}]
```

Here `m` is the root of `BesselJ[1, m] == 0`

Comment: `In[29]:= FunctionPoles[ii, r]

Out[29]= {{0, 2}}` This shows that the integration path cannot contain the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Try transformation of variable `r->R0 \[Rho]` (assuming `R0>0`)

```
int=Integrate[(1/\[Rho]^2)*BesselJ[0, m \[Rho]]*
D[BesselJ[0, m \[Rho]], {  \[Rho], 2}], {\[Rho],  \[Rho]0 ,  1}, 
Assumptions -> { 0 < \[Rho]0 < 1}]/R0


(*(1/(2 R0 \[Rho]0))m^2 (2 \[Rho]0 HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2)}, {1,1}, -m^2] - 
2 HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2)}, {1,1}, -m^2 \[Rho]0^2] - \[Rho]0
HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2), 3/2}, {1/2, 2, 2}, -m^2] + 
HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2), 3/2}, {1/2, 2, 2}, -m^2 \[Rho]0^2])*)
```

Substitution of result `m` from `BesselJ[1, m] == 0`:

```
mi = Values@NSolve[{BesselJ[1, m] == 0, 0 <= m < 20}, m] // Flatten

Plot[Table[int R0 , {m, mi}], {\[Rho]0, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True,AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]0", "int R0"}]
```

[image]

Integral seems to be convergent for the values `mi`

Comment: Does this mean that the integral is convergent in `0 < rho < infinity` ?

Comment: No, convergence  only for `0 < rho<1`

Answer (score 1):

With

```
 Limit[Integrate[ r^-2 BesselJ[0, r] D[BesselJ[0, r], {r, 2}], r]
 r -> \[Infinity]]
```

$$\frac{20}{9 \pi }$$

and

```
    Series[Integrate[ r^-2 BesselJ[0, r] D[BesselJ[0, r], {r, 2}], r],
       {r,   0, 2}]
```

$$\frac{1}{2 r}+\frac{5 r}{16}+O\left(r^3\right)$$

its obvious that the integral is finite for any interval with strictly positive lower bound

Comment: +1. Also `Series[r^-2 BesselJ[0, r] D[BesselJ[0, r], {r, 2}], {r, Infinity, 
   3}] // Normal` results in `-((2 Cos[\[Pi]/4 - r]^2)/(\[Pi] r^3))`, confirming the convergence at infinity.